# UNIX command for pid running in background

Tags: unix

I am running various programs on Unix in the background. Each program is outputting into a different file, e.g.:

```
python eventsim.py > logfile &
python eventsim.py > log1 &
```

Now say I want to kill the process that outputs to the file log1, but I no longer remember what its pid is. Is there a way I can retrieve that info?

Answer (score 5):

Check the [jobs](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/jobs/) command will print the currently running jobs.

```
jobs
```

After you get the process id, you can use [fg](http://ss64.com/bash/fg.html) or [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill).

You can also use a combination of [ps](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) and [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep), or [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) (if available):

```
pgrep eventsim.py
```

Note: This isn't really programming related and might be better answered at https://superuser.com/.

Comment: so using jobs, nothing comes up. I am using bash and I get nothing, however on a sever that I am connected to uses tcsh and I get what I want using jobs...why? Isn't bash Unix?

Comment: bash (and tcsh) is a shell that is commonly on unix systems, but it is not unix. `jobs` should work on both if you have a background process.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see the full command line using [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)(1):

```
ps auxwww | grep '[l]og1'
```

The PID will be in the second column.

Comment: For some reason, it gives different pid

Comment: A different PID to what?

Comment: say the pid for python eventsim.py is 722, when i use that command, i get a pid of 1532

Comment: I thought you didn't know the PID? Are you sure 722 isn't the PID of another instance of `python eventsim.py`? `grep '[l]og1'` was specifically to find instances writing to that particular file.

Answer (score 1):

try this command:

```
ps aux | grep 'eventsim.py' | awk '{print $2,$11,$12}'
```

the output is:

```
1595 python eventsim.py
```

1595 is the pid number

and now:

```
kill <pid-number>
```

and the proccess will terminate

Comment: I would also like to see the output file

Comment: Why use `grep` and not `ps aux | awk '/eventsim.py/ {print $2,$11,$12}'`?

Comment: Johnsyweb because i'm learn about awk script ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around: kill -STOP [pid] provides a confirmation that shows what I am looking for. Thanks for the help!